# Adcionar navigation-Drawer layout em um projeto com activitys ja criadas

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation-drawer

Criei um projeto androod com kotlin todo, mas sem o navdrawer layout, agora preciso colocar o navdrawer e incluir as activity que tenho nele

Se alguem souber com encaixar as activity dentro dos seus navdrawer me ajudaria bastante

Comment: Postar o código das activities também nos ajuda

Answer (score 0):

Para começar a usar o ***DrawerLayout*** e o ***NavigationView*** em seu projeto, você precisará importar as bibliotecas de suporte e design do Android. Portanto, adicione-os ao arquivo **build.gradle** do seu módulo para importá-los.

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
}
```

Além disso, inclua o ***DrawerLayout*** e também o ***NavigationView*** no arquivo **res/layout/activlty_main.xml**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_nav" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Aqui nós criamos um ***DrawerLayout*** com o ID ***drawerLayout***. A propriedade ***tools:openDrawer*** é usada para exibir a ***Navigation Drawer*** quando o layout XML é aberto na visualização de design do Android Studio.

Depois de adicionar o ***DrawerLayout***, criamos um layout filho que aponta para ***@layout/toolbar***.

Aqui está o meu arquivo ***toolbar.xml.*** Este arquivo simplesmente tem um ***LinearLayout*** e um ***Toolbar***.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
</LinearLayout>
```

No ***NavigationView***, você pode ver que adicionamos o atributo ***android:layout_gravity*** com o valor start. Isso é usado para posicionar o ***Navigation Drawer*** saindo da esquerda, se deseja que ele saia da direita utilize o valor end. No nosso caso ele sairá da esquerda.

Também incluímos o atributo ***app: headerLayout*** que aponta para ***@layout/nav_header***. Isto irá adicionar uma View como um cabeçalho do menu de navegação.

Aqui está o meu arquivo de layout ***nav_header.xml***:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/nav_header"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="160dp"
              android:background="@color/colorAccent"
              android:clickable="true"
              android:focusable="true"
              android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
              android:gravity="bottom"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:padding="16dp"
              android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/nav_header_imageView"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nav_header_textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:text="AndroidPro"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Esse arquivo de layout simplesmente possui um **LinearLayout**, um **ImageView** e um **TextView**.

Para incluir os itens de menu para no **Navigation Drawer**, podemos usar o atributo **app:menu** com um valor que aponta para um arquivo de menu.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        app:menu="@menu/menu_nav" />
```

Aqui está o arquivo de menu **res/menu/menu_nav.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group>
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_item_one"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
            android:title="Item 1" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_item_two"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_agenda"
            android:title="Item 2" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_item_three"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_call"
            android:title="Item 3" />
    </group>
    <group android:id="@+id/group_menu">
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_item_four"
            android:title="Item 4" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_item_five"
            android:title="Item 5" />
    </group>
    <item android:title="Title 1">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/nav_item_six"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
                android:title="Item 6" />
            <item android:id="@+id/nav_item_seven"
                android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_compass"
                android:title="Item 7" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Nós definimos um **Menu** usando o  que serve como um container para itens de menu. Um  cria um MenuItem, que representa um único item em um **menu**.

Nós então definimos nosso primeiro grupo de menu usando o . Um  serve como um contêiner invisível para elementos . Cada um dos elementos  possui um ID, um Ícone e um Título. Note que uma linha horizontal será desenhada no final de cada  quando mostrada no **Navigation Drawer**.

Um  também pode conter um elemento aninhado  para criar um submenu – fizemos exatamente isso em nosso último . Observe que este último  tem uma propriedade de título.

Nós pederíamos configurar um menu utilizando, por exemplo, uma **ListView**. Mas, configurando o **Navigation Drawer** com um menu, automaticamente é configurado o thema do **Material Design**!

Inicialização de Componentes
Em seguida, vamos inicializar as instâncias de nosso **DrawerLayout** e **ActionBarDrawerToggle**. E vamos fazer isso dentro do método **onCreate()** da MainActivity.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
    }
}
```